# Payslip after leaving the organization?

Tags: job-change

How do I get may Payslip as i had left the organization 4-5 months back ?
The payslips were available on hr-workways. but as I have the organization my employee id are not working. What can be done to retrieve the payslip. ?

Comment: Just ask them to send you the payslips.

Comment: Why would they issue a payslip for May if you stopped working last December or January?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton OP probably wants a copy of a past payslip.

Comment: @chrislnEdmonton I left the org in november... I need the payslips of the last 3-4 months while i was working.

Answer (score 7):

Email the HR department to ask them for your last pay slip.

Comment: While this does answer the question, a good answer is more than one sentence long and provides explanation and support for your proposed solution.